# Can't open .php pages in any browser

Tags: linux, php, browser, iceweasel

When I try to open a php page e.g.: http://minetest.net/download.php
My browser doesnt want open it and instead it wants to download the php file.

Comment: Please only write "on linux" if it's really solely Linux and you are sure about it (e.g. because you tested it). Only add the kind of information to the title that might help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem with your browser, it's a problem with the website:

```
% curl -LI http://minetest.net/download.php
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.7.12
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 10:39:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.minetest.net/download.php

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.7.12
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 10:39:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
Content-Length: 382
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 20:15:30 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 08:03:51 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
X-Served-By: cache-ams4125-AMS
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
X-Timer: S1444905591.411330,VS0,VE85
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Celeron55s-Proxy-Cache: MISS
X-Celeron55s-Proxy-Thinks-This-Is: Dynamic content
```

Notice the line `Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php`. nginx shouldn't be serving you PHP itself, it should be serving you the result of processing the PHP on the server side, and returning HTML content with `Content-Type: text/html`. Since your browser doesn't know how to display files with the mimetype `application/x-httpd-php`, it downloads it.

This is strictly an issue with the server, not your browser. Your browser did the most reasonable thing it could do by downloading this file. Tell the webmaster to fix their PHP/nginx installation instead. :-)

As an aside, it seems that PHP page is trying to redirect you to [this](http://www.minetest.net/downloads/) download page, which you could just go to instead.